# Calling stored procedures with multiple results tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-mars

Am having difficulty getting both tables from a stored procedure. So far it only return the first table, my code is below:

```
seat_plan seatP = new seat_plan();
apiModel api = new apiModel();
try
{
    seatP.seats = new apiModel().Database.SqlQuery<seat_plan_seat>("EXEC LWP_SEAT_PLAN {0}", perf);
    seatP.labels = new apiModel().Database.SqlQuery<seat_plan_label>("EXEC LWP_SEAT_PLAN {0}", perf);
}
catch (Exception) { }

return seatP;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume when you say MVC, you really mean Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the results of your stored procedure into a DataSet object and then pulling data from the various tables following the example:

```
queryResultsDataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows[rowIndex][columnName]
```